# SPS 2013 - Host Named Site Collections - AAM issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping, hnsc

We are having an issue regarding Host Named Site Collections.

Currently we have a Web Application: `web01.net`

In that web application we have multiple site collections using Host named site collections `web01.net/sites/Globalmethods`, and the Host name site collection is `globalmethods.net`

Currently we are not updating the AAM because we are using directly HNSC (Host Named Site Collection) but we are having some issues in the ULS Logs.

We detected that we have a lot of this kind of errors in the ULS Logs:

> Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  Users or services are accessing the site web01.net with the URL globalmethods.net.  This may cause incorrect links to be stored or returned to users.  If this is expected, add the URL globalmethods.net as an AAM response URL.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you have here.  Do you mean you are using path based sites and HNSC in the same web app?  How did you configure the Site collection? Do you have anything else configured in IIS like Rewrite module or anything external that may be modifying requests?

Comment: Hi Jesus, the Web App is created web01.net but then the host named site collection is created trought powershell in order to assign the url to the site collection.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response - my guess here is that you didn't create a root site collection.  After you create your WebApp, generally you would create a single path based site collection which serves as the root site collection.  After which you can then deploy your Host Named Site Collections.

I would deploy a single site collection at the root the traditional way (you don't have to grant permission or access to anything) and see if that clears up your errors.

Comment: Hi Jesus,

Yes, these are the following site collections created on the Web Application

/sites/AppCatalog
globalmethods.net
globalmethods.net/sites/release
globalmethods.net/sites/shared